# Open and Close an Excel sheet from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do you use MS Access 2010 to open an Excel 2003 sheet. And how do you close the same Excel 2003 sheet?

To open a report in Access you simply write:

```
DoCmd.Open acReport, ReportName
```

Is there a similar way of opening an excel sheet?

Comment: `"What is the neccessary SQL or VBA code"` What have you tried so far? What issues have you encountered? This isn't a code writing service.  IF you want someone to write it for you there are numerous freelancing sites where you can pay a fair price. I'll do it for 200 Euro. You might get cheaper, but any decent programmer will charge a lot more than I. Hint: `Workbook.Close`

Comment: To avoid the deluge of downvotes, and closing questions: read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25935059/edit) your question and give all the necessary details. A quick [Google Search](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=open%20excel%20file%20vba) turns up **loads** of answers. Also see the [search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
Option Compare Database
Dim xlApp As Object

Private Sub CommandOpen_Click()

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

''xlApp.Workbooks.Open "FileName", True, False

End Sub


Private Sub CommandExit_Click()
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Fair play for answering, I personally am a bit reluctant to write code for someone for free, but mostly not spoon feeding someone too much, they will never learn from it. And there's always the risk of enabling [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) especially when Google and Stack Overflow have TONS of good answers to this.